# Should javascript geolocation prompt user to turn on location services?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, geolocation

I am using the geolocation functionality to track user's locations with javascript. More specifically, I am using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition. My site works fine. When I visit my site on my Android device it prompts if I would like to allow the site to track my location. I tap allow (as well as remember my preference).

After success with that I turned off location services on my phone and went back to the site. It didn't prompt me for permission again (since I told it to remember my preference last time but it didn't prompt me to turn on my location services either. Needless to say at that point my site never got any geolocation data from the browser.

My question: Is there some way to prompt the user to turn on their location services programatically? If I had not saved my security preference and it prompted me to allow again would it have turned on or asked me to turn on location services? I would hate to have to tell the user they need to go into their cell phone's preferences to enable it.

Comment: So you're asking if JS can turn on geolocation services on the handset? No.

Comment: it would be nice if the browser at least asked the user if they want to turn location services on.

Comment: That largely depends upon the device, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's browser specific or to be more exact - application specific. What you could do is wait e.g. half a minute or a minute for the location and if it is not available show a warning to the user.

Comment: But that isn't an indication that the location services are turned off, just that they're unavailable. You don't know if the problem is temporary (i.e. no coverage) or semi-permanent (i.e. services disabled by the user).

Comment: in Chrome its throwing Permission denied. In the default Android browser its throwing Position unavailable.

Comment: Yes, you could say you are at the mercy of the browser, but you could simply show a warning to the user and he could check. If you are not focused on a single platform then your user will probably know  best what to check.